# Issue with Entity Reference and Views

Tags: views, entities

I'm needing to change the 'Entity Selection' mode on an entity reference field for a content type from 'Simple' to 'Views: Filter by an entity reference view'.

However, the 'Views: Filter by an entity reference view' option does not appear. 'Simple' is the only option. I have tried creating new test fields to see if it's an issue with that particular field, however this issue persists across new fields as well.

Additionally, I've noticed that if I try to create a new view, the option to change the display type to 'Entity Reference' is also missing.

I've been unable to determine what is preventing these options from appearing, and I'm wondering if the issue might be with either the Entity Reference or Views modules themselves. I haven't been able to locate someone with a similar problem on Stack Overflow or the Drupal forums yet.

Any thoughts on what I might be overlooking that could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was an issue with the Entity Reference module after all.

This site is part of a multi-site setup that was using an older version of Entity Reference which I was hesitant to update due to potential repercussions. After updating the module, everything is working as intended.